# Pandas - sum column values for a given row with duplicate column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I would like somebody help me with the following task I’m trying to resolve.
Please see below mock-up of my dataframe.

```
df= 
Date, Investor, Payment, Investor, Payment,
25/02/2018, Investor1, 100,000, Investor2, 200,000
25/04/2020, Investor1, 110,000, Investor2, 220,000
```

I would to get sum of all payments for a given date, i.e.

SUM all payments for a given date where column name is df[‘Payment’].
Note that column Name Payment repeats multiple times.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hi Mayank, thanks for getting back to me, my expected output is:

Comment: Hi Mayank, thanks for getting back to me, my expected output is: Header-> Date SumPayments; first Line -> 25/02/2018 300,000; Second Line -> 25/04/2020 330,000

Comment: I hope it is makes sense, I’m doing it on my phone

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

First combine duplicate columns to one column by `sum()`:

```
In [556]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[556]: 
         Date    Investor   Payment    Investor  Payment
0  25/02/2018   Investor1    100000   Investor2   200000
1  25/04/2020   Investor1    110000   Investor2   220000

In [563]: df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum() 
In [562]: df
Out[562]: 
         Date              Investor  Payment
0  25/02/2018   Investor1 Investor2   300000
1  25/04/2020   Investor1 Investor2   330000
```

Then, group on `Date` and find sum of `Payment`:

```
In [564]: df.groupby('Date')['Payment'].sum()                                                                                                                                                               
Out[564]: 
Date
25/02/2018    300000
25/04/2020    330000
Name: Payment, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @TomasNemeth You can always rename columns like: 
`df.rename(columns={'Payment.1' : 'Payment', 'Investor.1': 'Investor'})`.

This will create duplicate column names.